# get or post data in jquery (show url on browser line)

Tags: php, jquery, html, .htaccess

Okay, i have a job to do before tomorrow morning..

i'm working on some jquery. 
Where i load some external file data..

What i really want to know, is how am i going to load some data when i $.post / or $.get some data through jquery

Send request into jquery `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.view.load('prices');">hey </a>`

and the same time change the url browser to ex. mywebsite.com/prices/ without making the refresh on the page

is it possible, and how to do ?

```
// edit (not working)

    <li><a href="/prices"  onclick="$.view.show('prices');"> <span>prices</span></a></li>

jquery: $('a.prices').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.view.show('prices');
        });`
```

but can see that some of the others samples are not that easy to make it work..

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/prices/" class="priceLink">hey</a>

$('a.priceLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.view.load('prices');
});
```

When the user click the link, the normal URL will be shown on the browser line, but won't get visited (because of [preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29)) and `$.view.load('prices');` will thus load in that content without refreshing the page.

EDIT: @William - please try this:

```
<li><a href="/prices" class="prices"><span>prices</span></a></li>

    $('a.prices').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.view.show('prices');
    });
```

Comment: ...and those links are visitable if Javascript is off/unavailable.

Comment: its not working :-/ 
it just send me to an Not Found page... :(

Comment: @william - did you give your link the priceLink class as above? Can you paste what you have tried?

Comment: @william - you're almost there, but you still have the onclick in the anchor tag which you need to get rid of, also you did not give it a class as per my example. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a jQuery plugin called [URL Utils](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-url-utils-plugin/) - there's also a great [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/175-ajax-history-and-bookmarks) that shows you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only change the url for the anchor part (www.url.com/#anchor), and nothing else (without a browser refresh). Perhaps you can use [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution!!

http://nix.lv/history/demo.html

took me about 10min to install, and it just work perfectly..(i did some mod )

solution:

```
<li><a href="/prices" rel="history" class="prices"><span>prices</span></a></li>
```

jquery(download the plugin at the link above):

```
$.history.init(pageload); 

    // PageLoad function
 function pageload(hash) {

    // hash doesn't contain the first # character.
    if(hash) {
        $.view.show(hash); // load pages
    } else {
        // start page
        $.view.show(load_from_start);
    }
}
```

try it.. :)